# I need help refactoring code to conform to the Single Responsibility principle

Tags: swift, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I'm currently trying to understand the SOLID principles by reading the book called `Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby`. The first principle is the single responsibility, the way I understand this concept is that a class/method should only have one responsibility or reason to change.

In the code below I have a Calculate class which is responsible for (4) four different operations, `add`,`subtract`,`multiply` and `divide`, which to me doesn't conform to the Single Responsibility theory.

Can someone be so kind and refactor the following class in a way that it adheres to the `Single Responsibility`?

I know this could be a very opinionated topic but I really need to understand this concept better.

FYI - For simplicity I'm using Ints only, which I know it is not ideal for divisions and subtractions.

```
class Calculate{

    let num1:Int
    let num2:Int

    init(firstNum:Int, secondNum:Int){
        num1 = firstNum
        num2 = secondNum
    }

    func add()->Int{

        let total = num1 + num2

        return total
    }

    func subtract()->Int{

        let total = num1 - num2

        return total
    }

    func multiply()->Int{

        let total = num1 + num2

        return total
    }

    func divide()->Int{

        let total = num1 / num2

        return total
    }

}


let operation = Calculate(firstNum:5 , secondNum:5)
print(operation.divide())
```

Comment: This certainly conforms to SRP. `Calculate` is composed of a family of related algorithms used to perform its function of calculating. I wouldn't refactor this.

Comment: @Mister Epic - Oh, so the class can have as many actions (methods) as it needs as long as these actions are related to what the class does, on this case since addition, subtraction etc., are considered part of a calculation, it is ok to be inside the `Calculate` class, right? The reason I was confused is because all four methods are returning a value and are exposed to the outside world, but in theory they operate with the same data (arguments).

Answer (score 1):

The single responsibility means the class should have only one logic functionality.

Therefore if you have calculator, it is perfectly ok, it can calculate. The "single" does not mean "single method". Calculater can sum, divide etc. right? So yeah, this is exactly what Calculator class method should do.

If you want for example connect two Calculator classes, adding method "connectToAnotherCalculator" is against SRP. The correct approach is to create Connector class, which should handle the communication between calculators.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest better design. Imagine you have to add many other operations: percent, square root, or even sine. Your calculator will grow at thousands of lines. What about testing? Assume, we have already tested calculator. Now we need to test it again after each operation. So, adding new operation will cost us changing calculator, changing all places where it is used and many tests that cover it.

But we can make calculator with single responsibility - calculate(operation):
1) Now we can use everywhere calculator->calculate(operation), cover it with tests and make them passed.
2) For every new operation we just adding new operation class and tests for it. We can easily change any operation without even touching calculator and objects that uses it.

Comment: It sounds interesting, something like using a protocol (interface)? I have heard the phrase "Program to an interface not to a class" is that what you are suggesting? I will try to improve my original code and will post here.

Comment: Yes, interfaces have more benefits vs concrete classes. You can use interfaces and then change concrete implementation in one place only. If you cover your code with unit-tests it also allows you to inject mocks as implementation of your interfaces

Answer (score 0):

@Denis Efimov Here is the code I came up with after your suggestion. This [video from Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/solid-principles-in-php/episodes/2) helped me a lot, it is in PHP but it was easy to translate it to Swift.

I'm only showing two operations (`Addition` and `Multiplication`) but I could easily add as many as I wanted to. Please note that for simplicity I'm only using `Int`s.

```
protocol Operation{

    func equation()->Int

}

class Calculator{

    func calculate(operation:Operation)->Int{

        return operation.equation()

    }
}

class Addition:Operation{

    var addendOne:Int
    var addendTwo:Int

    init(addendOne:Int, addendTwo:Int){

        self.addendOne = addendOne
        self.addendTwo = addendTwo
    }

    func equation()->Int{
        return self.addendOne + self.addendTwo
    }

}

class Multiplication:Operation{

    var multiplicand:Int
    var multiplier:Int

    init(multiplicand:Int, multiplier:Int){

        self.multiplicand = multiplicand
        self.multiplier = multiplier
    }

    func equation()->Int{
        return self.multiplicand * self.multiplier
    }

}


let addition = Addition(addendOne:5, addendTwo:5)
let multiplication = Multiplication(multiplicand:5, multiplier:5)

let calculator = Calculator()

print(calculator.calculate(addition))
print(calculator.calculate(multiplication))
```

What do you guys think about this code, does that look like a better approach? Does that adheres more to the `SOLID` principal (`SO`)?.

Thanks

Comment: Yes that would work but you are on the wrong track. The design in your question DOES conform with SRP. There is no point in introducing a new scublass for each method that you want to add to a class.

Comment: I see your point, my code now adheres more to the "`open close`" principle **S`O`LID**, right? Everything is starting to make sense.

Comment: Your second approach adheres with the OCP as well as the first approach does. Well, you could see it that way but I thinkt this is not the best example for an OCP implementation. Adding additional methods does not violate the OCP.